# Getting list of CSS properties

Tags: css

Hi
Is there a way to check what CSS properties are applied to an HTML Element.
I dont want any browser plugin. Using javascript, I want to get a list of all CSS properties set on an html element. If thats not possible, I can always write 100 lines of code and checking the value like if($("div").css("background-color").length > 0){}, for each and every css property.

Comment: What do you want to use? JavaScript? Browser plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, I also recommend you using inspecting tools as Firebug, Webkit Inspector and Dragonfly.

But if you need just a quick check on CSS properties, you can create a quick script. There are some DOM methods and properties that becomes handy, like element.currentStyle and element.getComputedStyle().

Check this out http://blog.stchur.com/2006/06/21/css-computed-style/

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your browser, you can use the following plugins or tools (linked where necessary):

- **Firefox** - [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/)  (download the addon, restart and press F12 to open)
- **Google Chrome, Safari** - Webkit Inspector (CTRL+SHIFT+I to bring it up)
- **Opera - Dragonfly** (CTRL+SHIFT+I)
- **Internet Explorer 5.5-7** - [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=95E06CBE-4940-4218-B75D-B8856FCED535&displaylang=en) (press the icon near your address bar)
- **Internet Explorer 8+ - IE Developer Tools** (press F12 to open)

Comment: Stack Overflow uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), not BBCode, to format posts.

Comment: Heh, fixed. Thanks. Would be helpful if there was a prominent link to the syntax on the edit page.

Comment: All the adverts/rubbish on the RHS have trained my brain to totally ignore the sidebar. Can't believe I missed it!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to be a bit more elaborate. But for now [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) seems to fit your description.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript :

```
Object.keys(document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0].style).join(',')
```

This instruction will list all CSS properties : 
[image]

To check if a css property is applied : Use the following function :

```
String.prototype.isCssProp=function(hTMLElement){
  if(hTMLElement instanceof HTMLElement){
        var all=','+Object.keys(hTMLElement.style).join(',')+',';
          if(all.indexOf(','+this+',')===-1){
              return false;
          }else{
               return true
           }
    }else{
       return false;
    }

}
```

And then , use it :

```
var hTMLELement=document.getElementById('myid');
"color".isCssProp(hTMLELement);
"background-color".isCssProp(hTMLELement);
```

Comment: why make it a string and search that when you could search the array itself?