# How to get widget's CSS properties?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I try to make a web application with shiny and I would like to know if it exists a function that display the CSS property of widgets.

Let's see with an example. I spent much time to find several CSS properties of the actionButton.

```
# Actionbutton
      actionButton(inputId = "submit", label = "SUBMIT"),

# Used properties
      tags$style("button#submit { 
                 margin-left: auto;
                 margin-right: auto;
                 display:block; 
                 background-color:#808080; 
                 padding: 5px 25px; 
                 font-size:1.5em;  
                 letter-spacing:0.05em; 
                 text-transform:uppercase ;
                 color:#FFFFFF;")
```

However, sources are limited for others widgets like fileInput, Checkbox group
 etc …

NB - I tried to find the answer by myself [Getting list of CSS properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900594/getting-list-of-css-properties) but all links are dead.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean what CSS properties are applied to elements by default, or what CSS properties are possible? Any browser you're using to view the app should have developer tools that let you inspect elements and see styles applied to any element

Comment: Hello Camille ! sorry for the wait ! Yes, it's exactly that I want to use ! Pryore gave me the solution ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your shiny dashboard into a web-browser and then right-click on the page and select Inspect Element (Q).

You can launch your app in a web browser using `launch.brower = TRUE` to your runApp code. For example,

```
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server) launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Once you select Inspect Element (Q), you will be able to hover over elements in your page, including your widgets, to display CSS information. In your case, hover over your widget and click on it to obtain CSS properties. I've attached a photo below to indicate what this looks like.

[image]